# Selenium not able to identify element during execution

Tags: selenium

I am trying to sign in into following website. But Selenium is not able to type text in username field.
http://www.livejournal.com/login.bml

It is throwing following error

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Xpath for username field = `//input[@id='user']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two input fields with same id ("user") located on page. First is hidden, so you need to handle second one. Try this `XPath`:

```
(//input[@id="user"])[2]
```